# Why is my FPS camera rolling, once and for all?

Tags: python, opengl, graphics, rotation, quaternions

If I ignore the sordid details of quaternions algebra I think I understand the maths behind rotation and translation transformations. But still fail to understand what I am doing wrong.

**Why is my camera rolling once and for all!?** :)

And to be a bit more specific, how should I compute the camera View matrix from its orientation (rotation matrix)?

I am writing a minimalistic 3d engine in Python with a scene Node class that handles the mechanics of rotation and translation of 3d objects. It has methods that expose the Rotation and Translation matrices as well as the Model matrix.

There is also a CameraNode class, a subclass of Node, that also exposes the View and Projection matrices (projection is not the problem, so we can ignore it).

### Model Matrix

In order to correctly apply the transformations I multiply the matrices as follows:

```
PxVxM x v
```

i.e first the Model, then the View and finally the Projection.

Where M is computed by first applying the rotation and then the translation:

```
M = TxR
```

Here's the code:

```
class Node():
    # ...

    def model_mat(self):
        return self.translation_mat() @ self.rotation_mat() @ self.scaling_mat()

    def translation_mat(self):
        translation = np.eye(4, dtype=np.float32)
        translation[:-1, -1] = self.position  # self.position is an ndarray
        return translation

    def rotation_mat(self):
        rotation = np.eye(4, dtype=np.float32)
        rotation[:-1, :-1] = qua.as_rotation_matrix(self.orientation)  # self.orientation is a quaternion object
        return rotation
```

### View Matrix

I am computing the View matrix based on the camera position and orientation, as follows:

```
class CameraNode(Node):
    # ...

    def view_mat(self):
        trans = self.translation_mat()
        rot = self.rotation_mat()
        trans[:-1, 3] = -trans[:-1, 3]  # <-- efficient matrix inversion
        rot = rot.T                     # <-- efficient matrix inversion
        self.view = rot @ trans
        return self.view
```

Please correct me if I am wrong. Since we can only move and rotate the world geometry (as opposed to moving/rotating the camera) I have to multiply the matrices in the reverse order and also the oposite transformation (effectively the inverse of each transformation matrix). In other words, moving the camera away from an object can also be seen as moving the object away from the camera.

### Input to rotation

Now, here's how I convert keyboard input into camera rotation. When I press the right/left/up/down arrow keys I am calling the following methods with some pitch/yaw angle:

```
def rotate_in_xx(self, pitch):
    rot = qua.from_rotation_vector((pitch, 0.0, 0.0))
    self.orientation *= rot

def rotate_in_yy(self, yaw):
    rot = qua.from_rotation_vector((0.0, yaw, 0.0))
    self.orientation *= rot
```

### Behaves wrong but rotation matrix is correct

And this is what I get:

[image: behaves wrong but rot matrix is correct]

[image: behaves wrong but rot matrix is correct]

Now, confusingly, if I change the above methods to:

```
class CameraNode(Node):

    def view_mat(self):
        view = np.eye(4)
        trans = self.translation_mat()
        rot = self.rotation_mat()
        trans[:-1, 3] = -trans[:-1, 3]
        # rot = rot.T                     # <-- COMMENTED OUT
        self.view = rot @ trans
        return self.view

    def rotate_in_xx(self, pitch):
        rot = qua.from_rotation_vector((pitch, 0.0, 0.0))
        self.orientation = rot * self.orientation  # <-- CHANGE
```

I can make the camera behave correctly as an FPS camera, but the rotation matrix does not seem right.

[image: behaves well but rot matrix is wrong]

[image]

Please could someone shed some light?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your last example you only deal with pitch, Do you have the same result if you keep only pitch in your first example ? I don't think you want to chain your rotation the way you are doing (pitch then yaw) play a bit with http://www.ctralie.com/Teaching/COMPSCI290/Materials/EulerAnglesViz/. Then you may want to have alook on arc ball

Comment: @Draykoon, thanks for your comment. If what you are suggesting is: "instead of setting `self.orientation = rot * self.orientation` inside `def rotate_in_xx(self, pitch)` set `self.orientation = rot * self.orientation` inside `def rotate_in_yy(self, yaw)`" then I take my hat off to you. Thanks, that solved my problem :)))

Comment: However I am not entirely sure I understand why that solved the problem. I believe this problem or something similar will eventually bite me again as soon as I add more complexity, e.g adding children nodes which for now I haven't really thought about it.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46741647/1210053) might help you understand the problem.

Comment: So now you only deal with yaw, right ? you mitght want to store your pitch and yaw on 2 separate variable and set ```self.orientation = quat.fromEuler(m_pitch, m_yaw, 0.0f) * m_initialForyardVector``` you might not want to do some "*=" cause in the next frame your new yaw is going to affect the previus roll etc ...

Comment: @Nico, I will take a look, thanks.

Comment: @Draykoon, I was hoping the quaternion would be enough to keep my node orientation, it seems redundant to keep yaw and pitch additionally to the orientation quaternion.

Comment: @Nico, thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In [my last answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54886220/why-is-my-fps-camera-rolling-using-euler-angles-not-quaternions-implementatio/54886631#54886631) to your issue, I told you why it's not a good idea to reuse your view matrix, because pitching and yawing don't commute. You're using quaternions now, but again, pitch and yaw quaternions don't commute. Just store the pitch value and the yaw value, and recalculate
the orientation from pitch and yaw whenever you need it.

```
def rotate_in_xx(self, pitch):
    self.pitch += pitch

def rotate_in_yy(self, yaw):
    self.yaw += yaw

def get_orientation():
    pitch_rotation = qua.from_rotation_vector((self.pitch, 0.0, 0.0))
    yaw_rotation = qua.from_rotation_vector((0.0, self.yaw, 0.0))
    return yaw_rotation * pitch_rotation
```

---

A note on how in your last screenshot the camera rotation matrix and object rotation matrix aren't identical: The object rotation and translation matrices (together the model matrix) describe the transformation from **object coordinates** to **world coordinates**, while the view matrix describes the transformation from **world coordinates** to **camera coordinates**.

So in order for the tripod to be displayed axis-aligned relative to your viewport, then the view rotation matrix must be the *inverse* of the model rotation matrix.

Comment: why do you say I am reusing the view matrix? I am using a quaternion to keep my nodes orientation. View matrix is computed when needed, from the quaternion. I don't think error accumulation is the problem here. This question differs from my previous one because, now I am using a quaternion as opposed to keeping the Euler angles.

Comment: on my last screenshot the camera rotation matrix and object rotation matrix are not identical indeed, I state that in the image itself, in a green colored message. And that was the whole reason for posting this question. In other words that second example show that I was able to achieve the FPS camera behavior but the orientation matrix was not correct, I show that comparing the camera rotation matrix with a reference object that is subject to the same rotation.

Comment: The view matrix is computed inside `def view_mat()`, I am inverting both the translation and rotation matrices with `trans[:-1, 3] = -trans[:-1, 3]` and `rot = rot.T`, respectively.

Comment: Right, your quaternion is not a view matrix, but quaternions corresponding to pitch and yaw don't commute either (i\*j != j\*i), so you'll run into the exact same problem as before.

Comment: I am not using a quaternion per pitch, yaw and angle, I am using a single quaternion to represent the the node orientation. I then generate rotation quaternions based on user input and then apply (multiply) the respective quaternion. Also quaternion multiplication is not commutative, I am aware of that. That is the reason why on my second example the camera behaves as expected. The problem was that the rotation matrix was not okay. But @Draykoon pertinent suggestion seems to have solved the problem.

Comment: Typo on my previous comment: "I am not using a quaternion per pitch, yaw and roll*"

Answer (score 0):

You should not accumulate all your Euler angle in one rotationMatrix, directionVector or Quaternion.

Doing stuff like:

```
vec3 euler = vec3(yaw, pitch, roll);
rot *= quaternion(euler)
or
self.orientation = quaternion(euler) * self.orientation
```

Each frame you add a rotation to an already existing rotation stored in your structure.

```
float deltaYaw = getInput();
float deltaPitch = getInput();
m_rotation = m_rotation * euler(deltaYaw, deltaRoll, 0.0f) 
is not equal to
m_rotation = rotationMatrix(m_yaw + deltaYaw, m_pitch + deltaRoll, 0.0f);
```

In one case you rotate an already rotated object with his new 3D frame by deltaYaw. The yaw you apply now will take in to account the roll you did previusly.

```
oldYaw * oldRoll * deltaYaw != (oldYaw * deltaYaw) * oldRoll
```

On the other you build the rotation from your mesh position to the requested euler angles.

Yes, you are right it's not a convenient way of handling camera, keeping yaw, pitch and roll in variables will lead to issues later on (gimBall lock, camera animation will get tricky ...). I would recommend to look at arcBall camera https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Modern_OpenGL_Tutorial_Arcball

Comment: Just to clarify, is this answering the question "Why is my camera rolling?" or just giving some advice "beware you might experience tiny amounts of rolling if you run the simulation for a long a period of time, which is not the culprit for the rolling you are experiencing right now"?
I am asking because after the change I made (see my comment to your first comment) things started working as I would expect, i.e the camera behaves like an FPS camera and the rotation matrix seems correct.